# Не работает русификация в процедуре

Tags: c++

У меня в программе есть две процедуры, которые работают с файлами. Программа проходит первую процедуру правильно (открывает файл, читает его, выводит на русском в командной строке, файл закрывается), но когда программа переходит на вторую функцию она читает её некорректно (при отладке в окне локальных переменных видно что туда попадает не текст на русском, а какой-то набор символов. Еще в командном окне он вместо этих строк выводит пустые строки). Помогите пожалуйста. Если нужно дополнительная информация спрашивайте.

```
int main () 
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

teory();

test();
...
}
```

Нашел решение: надо было сохранить файл txt с кодировкой ANSI

Comment: может предоставите чуточку больше кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `setlocale` влияет только на консоль, но не на чтение файлов.
2. Весьма вероятно, что в отладчике и должна быть какая-то муть, но это не точно.
3. С кодировкой файлов разбирайся.

Comment: если исключить первый пункт, то хочется написать "не является ответом на вопрос"

Comment: я по разбирался с кодировкой и оказалось что у меня была неправильная кодировка txt файла (UTH-8, а должно быть ANSI).

Comment: @VoidTimesWithNull Наоборот, в файле у вас как раз правильная кодировка. А для вывода в консоль ее, возможно, придется преобразовать.

Comment: @KoVadim, вроде вполне является)

Comment: @user7860670, по пустому выводу (вместо мусора), я бы предположил, что в файле utf16 вместо однобайтовой. Даже в utf8 нули не встречаются в нормальном тексте.

Comment: @Qwertiy ох ох. ну чего только не сделаешь за пару балов в репу